# unable to install json2html python module

Tags: python, python-module, json2html

I have been trying to install json2html python module from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json2html/ on a Mac machine using python setup.py install.

I have been getting the following error :

> Processing dependencies for json2html==0.2.1
>   Searching for ordereddict
>   Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ordereddict/
>   error: Connection reset by peer

Am not really sure what is going wrong as I am relatively new to Python.

Could some one please help me understand what am i missing and how can i address this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for posting such a stupid question. I needed to install the dependencies as well, before downloading json2html module.